# Selecting and ordering data from another table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables topsites, and tophits.

```
tophits has id, account, useragent, ip referral, time

topsites has id, name, email, url, return, active
```

Everytime someone clicks a link, it is stored in the tophits table with account being ID from topsites.

Basically I want to echo out the top hits for the day, so I figure I need to count how many hits there were for account=4 on time=today order by top

Here is what I have so far

```
$this->db->select('name, url');
$this->db->from('topsites');
$this->db->where('active' '1');
$this->db->join('tophits', 'tophits.id = topsites.account');
```

(This is for codeigniter)

I'm stuck. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Try this (untested)

When you are joining tables you need to specify in your select statements which table the given field belongs to.  Also CI by default protects fieldnames with backticks, BUT if you use SQL methods in your select/where statements, you need to give the second parameter `FALSE` to keep it from doing this, because it could malform your intended SQL methods.  You also need to add another where statement to restrict it to today.

```
$this->db->select('topsites.name, topsites.url, COUNT(tophits.id) AS hit_count',FALSE);
$this->db->from('topsites');
$this->db->where('active' '1');
$this->db->join('tophits', 'tophits.id = topsites.account');
$this->db->order_by('hit_count');    

$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. What is hit_count? How would I echo out topsites.name and .url? Like this?   foreach ($query->result() as $row)
       {
           echo $row->name;
           echo $row->url;
          
       }

Comment: hit_count is the alias we are giving the total Counted hits with `COUNT(tophits.id)`. And yes, you are correct on how to echo the results.